# Field summary with hooking one side

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, spatial-statistics, summarizing

I have line like Road and points are like housenumbers!

I have fields like side and ID_T
[image]

Highlighted blue apts having same ID_T because hooking one edge 
and side, if it hook right get R or else get L

---

- I need to select which apts are hooking only one side

---

Comment: A start could be converting lines to polygons. Then you can spatial join polygon id to the points. Same ID_T, different polygon ID = different sides. Or try [Near](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/near.htm) and then calculate Left Right North South by near angle.

Comment: What are "apts"?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: You have a tag for ArcGIS Desktop but make no mention of using that software in your question body.